# How to see if the permissions of a file are influenced by something else

Tags: command-line, permissions, scripts

I have a question. See this [link](https://forums.sonarr.tv/t/4-backups-every-day-because-before-update/27703).

I have the problem that sonarr can't update because the permissions aren't right for the file `styles.css.map`. Doing `sudo chmod 0664 styles.css.map` didn't work (eventho it should). At the end, markus101 says "After you fix the permissions, is something else mucking with them?".
There's a probability that something else (a script or process of the os) is messing with the permissions of `/opt/Sonarr/...`.

Is there a way to see if something is influencing the permissions of a file. Like `[process] changed the permissions of [file] from rw to r` or something like that. Just any way to see if a script or process (and which script or process then ofcourse) is messing with the permmissions. I don't have any scripts that I made my self that influence the permissions of the file.

Is there ANY way to find out?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your file on an NTFS or FAT32 filesystem?

Comment: `stat -f -c %T .` responds with `ext2/ext3`. `df -PTh . | awk '{print $2}'` responds with `ext4`. `df .` responds with `/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root`. When installing ubuntu, I set the os disk to lvm and added a second disk to that lvm later. So there are two drives in the system, setup as one big lvm with the os installed on it.

Comment: You can investigate permissions with my `pathlld` `bash` script. https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld